# A node in MySQL 5.7 innoDB cluster is crashed and unable to re-join the crashed node to the cluster

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-group-replication, mysql-innodb-cluster

We have a MySQL innodb cluster in one of our environments. One of the nodes in the cluster was crashed. Though, we were able to bring the crashed node online we were unable to join it to the cluster.

Can someone please help to recover/restore the node and join it to the cluster. We tried to use "dba.rebootClusterFromCompleteOutage()" but it didn't help.

Configuration: MySQL 5.7.24 Community Edition, CentOS 7, standard three node innodb cluster

Cluster Status:

```
MySQL  NODE02:3306 ssl  JS > var c=dba.getCluster()
MySQL  NODE02:3306 ssl  JS > c.status()
{
    "clusterName": "QACluster",
    "defaultReplicaSet": {
        "name": "default",
        "primary": "NODE03:3306",
        "ssl": "REQUIRED",
        "status": "OK_NO_TOLERANCE",
        "statusText": "Cluster is NOT tolerant to any failures. 1 member is not active",
        "topology": {
            "NODE02:3306": {
                "address": "NODE02:3306",
                "mode": "R/O",
                "readReplicas": {},
                "role": "HA",
                "status": "ONLINE"
            },
            "NODE03:3306": {
                "address": "NODE03:3306",
                "mode": "R/W",
                "readReplicas": {},
                "role": "HA",
                "status": "ONLINE"
            },
            "NODE01:3306": {
                "address": "NODE01:3306",
                "mode": "R/O",
                "readReplicas": {},
                "role": "HA",
                "status": "(MISSING)"
            }
        }
    },
    "groupInformationSourceMember": "mysql://clusterAdmin@NODE03:3306"
}
```

Errors logged in mysql error log:

```
2019-03-04T23:49:36.970839Z 3624 [Note] Slave SQL thread for channel 'group_replication_recovery' initialized, starting replication in log 'FIRST' at position 0, relay log './NODE01-relay-bin-group_replication_recovery.000001' position: 4
2019-03-04T23:49:36.985336Z 3623 [Note] Slave I/O thread for channel 'group_replication_recovery': connected to master 'mysql_innodb_cluster_r0429584112@NODE02:3306',replication started in log 'FIRST' at position 4
2019-03-04T23:49:36.988164Z 3623 [ERROR] Error reading packet from server for channel 'group_replication_recovery': The slave is connecting using CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_AUTO_POSITION = 1, but the master has purged binary logs containing GTIDs that the slave requires. (server_errno=1236)
2019-03-04T23:49:36.988213Z 3623 [ERROR] Slave I/O for channel 'group_replication_recovery': Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log: 'The slave is connecting using CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_AUTO_POSITION = 1, but the master has purged binary logs containing GTIDs that the slave requires.', Error_code: 1236
2019-03-04T23:49:36.988226Z 3623 [Note] Slave I/O thread exiting for channel 'group_replication_recovery', read up to log 'FIRST', position 4
2019-03-04T23:49:36.988286Z 41 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Terminating existing group replication donor connection and purging the corresponding logs.'
2019-03-04T23:49:36.988358Z 3624 [Note] Error reading relay log event for channel 'group_replication_recovery': slave SQL thread was killed
2019-03-04T23:49:36.988435Z 3624 [Note] Slave SQL thread for channel 'group_replication_recovery' exiting, replication stopped in log 'FIRST' at position 0
2019-03-04T23:49:37.016864Z 41 [Note] 'CHANGE MASTER TO FOR CHANNEL 'group_replication_recovery' executed'. Previous state master_host='NODE02', master_port= 3306, master_log_file='', master_log_pos= 4, master_bind=''. New state master_host='<NULL>', master_port= 0, master_log_file='', master_log_pos= 4, master_bind=''.
2019-03-04T23:49:37.030769Z 41 [ERROR] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Maximum number of retries when trying to connect to a donor reached. Aborting group replication recovery.'
2019-03-04T23:49:37.030798Z 41 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Terminating existing group replication donor connection and purging the corresponding logs.'
2019-03-04T23:49:37.051169Z 41 [Note] 'CHANGE MASTER TO FOR CHANNEL 'group_replication_recovery' executed'. Previous state master_host='<NULL>', master_port= 0, master_log_file='', master_log_pos= 4, master_bind=''. New state master_host='<NULL>', master_port= 0, master_log_file='', master_log_pos= 4, master_bind=''.
2019-03-04T23:49:37.069184Z 41 [ERROR] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Fatal error during the Recovery process of Group Replication. The server will leave the group.'
2019-03-04T23:49:37.069304Z 41 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Going to wait for view modification'
2019-03-04T23:49:40.336938Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Group membership changed: This member has left the group.'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did the following to restore the failed node from backup and able to recover the cluster state.

1)Below is the status of the cluster when one of the nodes failed (NODE01).

```
 MySQL  NODE02:3306 ssl  JS > var c=dba.getCluster()
 MySQL  NODE02:3306 ssl  JS > c.status()
{
    "clusterName": "QACluster",
    "defaultReplicaSet": {
        "name": "default",
        "primary": "NODE03:3306",
        "ssl": "REQUIRED",
        "status": "OK_NO_TOLERANCE",
        "statusText": "Cluster is NOT tolerant to any failures. 1 member is not active",
        "topology": {
            "NODE02:3306": {
                "address": "NODE02:3306",
                "mode": "R/O",
                "readReplicas": {},
                "role": "HA",
                "status": "ONLINE"
            },
            "NODE03:3306": {
                "address": "NODE03:3306",
                "mode": "R/W",
                "readReplicas": {},
                "role": "HA",
                "status": "ONLINE"
            },
            "NODE01:3306": {
                "address": "NODE01:3306",
                "mode": "R/O",
                "readReplicas": {},
                "role": "HA",
                "status": "(MISSING)"
            }
        }
    },
    "groupInformationSourceMember": "mysql://clusterAdmin@NODE03:3306"
}
```

2) Take mysqldump from the master node (healthy node) using the following command.

```
[root@NODE03 db_backup]# mysqldump --all-databases --add-drop-database --single-transaction --triggers --routines --port=mysql_port --user=root -p > /db_backup/mysql_dump_03062019.sql
Enter password:
Warning: A partial dump from a server that has GTIDs will by default include the GTIDs of all transactions, even those that changed suppressed parts of the database. If you don't want to restore GTIDs, pass --set-gtid-purged=OFF. To make a complete dump, pass --all-databases --triggers --routines --events.
```

3) Execute below step to remove the failed node from the cluster.

```
 MySQL  NODE03:3306 ssl  JS > var c=dba.getCluster()
 MySQL  NODE03:3306 ssl  JS > c.rescan()
Rescanning the cluster...

Result of the rescanning operation:
{
    "defaultReplicaSet": {
        "name": "default",
        "newlyDiscoveredInstances": [],
        "unavailableInstances": [
            {
                "host": "NODE01:3306",
                "label": "NODE01:3306",
                "member_id": "e2aa897d-1828-11e9-85b3-00505692188c"
            }
        ]
    }
}

The instance 'NODE01:3306' is no longer part of the HA setup. It is either offline or left the HA group.
You can try to add it to the cluster again with the cluster.rejoinInstance('NODE01:3306') command or you can remove it from the cluster configuration.
Would you like to remove it from the cluster metadata? [Y/n]: Y
Removing instance from the cluster metadata...

The instance 'NODE01:3306' was successfully removed from the cluster metadata.

 MySQL  NODE03:3306 ssl  JS > c.status()
{
    "clusterName": "QACluster",
    "defaultReplicaSet": {
        "name": "default",
        "primary": "NODE03:3306",
        "ssl": "REQUIRED",
        "status": "OK_NO_TOLERANCE",
        "statusText": "Cluster is NOT tolerant to any failures.",
        "topology": {
            "NODE02:3306": {
                "address": "NODE02:3306",
                "mode": "R/O",
                "readReplicas": {},
                "role": "HA",
                "status": "ONLINE"
            },
            "NODE03:3306": {
                "address": "NODE03:3306",
                "mode": "R/W",
                "readReplicas": {},
                "role": "HA",
                "status": "ONLINE"
            }
        }
    },
    "groupInformationSourceMember": "mysql://clusterAdmin@NODE03:3306"
}
```

4) Stop group replication if it is still running on failed node.

```
mysql> STOP GROUP_REPLICATION;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (1.01 sec)
```

5) Reset "gtid_executed" on the failed node.

```
mysql> show global variables like 'GTID_EXECUTED';
+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                                                                                      |
+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| gtid_executed | 01f27b9c-182a-11e9-a199-00505692188c:1-14134172,
e2aa897d-1828-11e9-85b3-00505692188c:1-12 |
+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> reset master;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> reset slave;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> show global variables like 'GTID_EXECUTED';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| gtid_executed |       |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

6) Disable "super_readonly_flag" on the failed node.

```
mysql> SELECT @@global.read_only, @@global.super_read_only;
+--------------------+--------------------------+
| @@global.read_only | @@global.super_read_only |
+--------------------+--------------------------+
|                  1 |                        1 |
+--------------------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET GLOBAL super_read_only = 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @@global.read_only, @@global.super_read_only;
+--------------------+--------------------------+
| @@global.read_only | @@global.super_read_only |
+--------------------+--------------------------+
|                  1 |                        0 |
+--------------------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

7) Restore the mysqldump from master on to the failed node.

```
[root@E2LXQA1ALFDB01 db_backup]# mysql -uroot -p < mysql_dump_03062019.sql
```

8) Once restore is completed enable "super_readonly_flag" on the failed node.

```
mysql> SELECT @@global.read_only, @@global.super_read_only;
+--------------------+--------------------------+
| @@global.read_only | @@global.super_read_only |
+--------------------+--------------------------+
|                  1 |                        0 |
+--------------------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET GLOBAL super_read_only = 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)


mysql> SELECT @@global.read_only, @@global.super_read_only;
+--------------------+--------------------------+
| @@global.read_only | @@global.super_read_only |
+--------------------+--------------------------+
|                  1 |                        1 |
+--------------------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

9) Finally add the failed node back to the innodb cluster.

```
MySQL  NODE03:3306 ssl  JS > c.addInstance('clusterAdmin@NODE01:3306');
A new instance will be added to the InnoDB cluster. Depending on the amount of
data on the cluster this might take from a few seconds to several hours.

Adding instance to the cluster ...

Please provide the password for 'clusterAdmin@NODE01:3306': *******************
Save password for 'clusterAdmin@NODE01:3306'? [Y]es/[N]o/Ne[v]er (default No):
Validating instance at NODE01:3306...

This instance reports its own address as NODE01
WARNING: The following tables do not have a Primary Key or equivalent column:
ephesoft.dlf, report.correction_type, report.field_details_ag, report_archive.correction_type, report_archive.field_details_ag, report_archive.global_data_ag

Group Replication requires tables to use InnoDB and have a PRIMARY KEY or PRIMARY KEY Equivalent (non-null unique key). Tables that do not follow these requirements will be readable but not updateable when used with Group Replication. If your applications make updates (INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE) to these tables, ensure they use the InnoDB storage engine and have a PRIMARY KEY or PRIMARY KEY Equivalent.

Instance configuration is suitable.
WARNING: On instance 'NODE01:3306' membership change cannot be persisted since MySQL version 5.7.24 does not support the SET PERSIST command (MySQL version >= 8.0.11 required). Please use the .configureLocalInstance command locally to persist the changes.
WARNING: On instance 'NODE02:3306' membership change cannot be persisted since MySQL version 5.7.24 does not support the SET PERSIST command (MySQL version >= 8.0.11 required). Please use the .configureLocalInstance command locally to persist the changes.
WARNING: On instance 'NODE03:3306' membership change cannot be persisted since MySQL version 5.7.24 does not support the SET PERSIST command (MySQL version >= 8.0.11 required). Please use the .configureLocalInstance command locally to persist the changes.
The instance 'clusterAdmin@NODE01:3306' was successfully added to the cluster.


 MySQL  NODE03:3306 ssl  JS > c.status()
{
    "clusterName": "QACluster",
    "defaultReplicaSet": {
        "name": "default",
        "primary": "NODE03:3306",
        "ssl": "REQUIRED",
        "status": "OK",
        "statusText": "Cluster is ONLINE and can tolerate up to ONE failure.",
        "topology": {
            "NODE01:3306": {
                "address": "NODE01:3306",
                "mode": "R/O",
                "readReplicas": {},
                "role": "HA",
                "status": "ONLINE"
            },
            "NODE02:3306": {
                "address": "NODE02:3306",
                "mode": "R/O",
                "readReplicas": {},
                "role": "HA",
                "status": "ONLINE"
            },
            "NODE03:3306": {
                "address": "NODE03:3306",
                "mode": "R/W",
                "readReplicas": {},
                "role": "HA",
                "status": "ONLINE"
            }
        }
    },
    "groupInformationSourceMember": "mysql://clusterAdmin@NODE03:3306"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> 2019-03-04T23:49:36.988213Z 3623 [ERROR] Slave I/O for channel
>   'group_replication_recovery': Got fatal error 1236 from master when
>   reading data from binary log: 'The slave is connecting using CHANGE
>   MASTER TO MASTER_AUTO_POSITION = 1, but the master has purged binary
>   logs containing GTIDs that the slave requires.', Error_code: 1236

Lets put it on simple terms: 
What this means is that you had 2 servers (S1,S2), one crashed (S2). While S2 was crashed you did some operations on S1 (transactions T1,T2) but at some point in time the binlogs on S1 were purged and they included info for T1.

Bottom line, S2 can't join the group because it knows it is missing T1, but there is no binlog file with that information available to transmit that info during recovery.

Sorry but there is no magic command here, that is just bad luck.
For now your best option is to provision S2 with data from S1 using some tool like dump or another in that group.

For the future you should recheck your binlog purge policies and make if possible the recovery of crashed machines a bit more fast.

Comment: Thank you. Any specific instructions to follow in restoring or recovering the failed node from the master backup?

Comment: Not an expert on DBA operations but if you search restore slave from backup you will find various answers. You need a tool to take the data from the running member and then replay that on the crashed member. Just a note that if your tool does not handle GTIDs you need to set GTID_purged on the recovering node after you restore the data.

Comment: sure, thank you. I'm working on it to fix. If I'm able to I will publish possible solution.